# Проблема с QT в Ubuntu

Tags: qt, c++, ubuntu

В общем возник такой «геморрой» с QT в Ubuntu (да и под виндой тоже было, как помню): установил **Develop Environment QT Creator 4** (вместе с Linguist, дизайнером и ассистентом). Устанавливал с центра приложений Ubuntu, всё прекрасно установилось. Вот начинаю подготавливать новый проект, как вдруг Qt «не может отыскать подходящие цели». Цели — это файлы `qmake`, которые участвуют в сборке приложения.

Так вот у меня беда: никак не хочет видеть файл `qmake-qt4`, что лежит в `/usr/bin`. Я создаю приложение в папке на рабочем столе, но QT никак «не может отыскать подходящие цели».

Comment: а точно с qmake проблема? Просто я так помню что он компилятора в зависимоти не имеет и его не ставит, хотя может это уже и поправили

Comment: Ну да, сам qmake-qt4 в целях стоит, но почему-то не распознается или не находится....а разве могут быть проблемы в чем-то другом, если не в qmake в таком случае?

Comment: Из консоли `qmake` работает?

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, да, проверил запуск из консоли, qmake прекрасно запускается.

Comment: sdk у Вас настроен?

Answer (score 2):

Создай проект в корневой папке, точнее в домашнем каталоге.
Еще бывают проблемы, когда в пути к каталогу встречаются определенные символы. У меня как то `qt` проект не собирался из за того? что я в его названии использовал символ "_"

ээээ `/home/Desktop` - это что??

Comment: Пробовал:

    /
    /usr
    /usr/bin
    /home
    /home/Desktop

Ничего не помогло...

Comment: есть предположение что у вас нет прав записи в этих дерикториях

Comment: Нет, проверил...проблема не в правах. Хоть директории рутовские, но все равно, права на них максимальные:

     drwxr-xr-x  11 root root  4096 2011-10-12 18:26 usr
     drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 36864 2012-08-02 12:16 bin

Comment: Никто кроме root-а писать туда не может.

Comment: Ок, ка же это можно исправить? Не подскажете, пожалуйста?

Comment: либо поменять хозяина директории через chown, либо права через chmod, но дело не в этом скорее всего. qmake же не пишет к себе ничего, а исполнять его можео

Comment: @SingleAsen, не думаю, что корежить линукс (chmod для /usr, /usr/bin и т.п.) это хорошая идея. Проще собрать из под рута.

--

Но, **проблема где-то в другом.** 

Лично я с **qt** дела не имел, но в принципе (насколько я понимаю) qmake должен сделать makefile. 

Т.е. надо читать документацию на qmake и запускать с ключами для trace/debug/verbose или что-то в этом духе. Ну, и внимательно читать протокол запуска и файлы, управляющие qmake-ом.

@SingleAsen, надеюсь Вы работаете из командной строки. В этом случае запустите `script` и потом выложите `typescript`. Попробуем разобраться.